# Chrome and Firefox not playing audio but system does

Tags: sound, firefox, google-chrome, pulseaudio

Last weekish my Chrome, Chromium and Firefox stopped playing any audio, wether it be from an `<audio>`, `<video>` or flash player. System tests play audio fine.

I am suspecting Chrome and Firefox need some sort of package to play audio and that package got updated or removed.

I have searched and found similar issues but not the same and the solutions did not apply or did not work.

How can I systematically debug this issue?

Update: I tried some pulseaudio inspection and looking at logs and running google-chrome from the command line but nothing good. But then had the idea to launch a webapp (hangouts) that let me choose the output device. In hangouts I changed from 'default source' to 'built-in analog stereo' and then 'play a test sound'... and I have sound! If I then choose what appears to be the default of 'high definitional audio controller digital...' then I get no sound.

So I think the issue lies around the system thinking the default audio source is the digital and not the analog destination.

Update2: My system sound settings only show one analog output. I do not have a digital output listed.

Answer (score 0):

Check in `pulseaudio`, `pavu` or whatever you use for volume control if firefox or chrome are sending the audio to the proper device. Else, it could be a jack related problem if `jackd` is running for applications such as arduor or some synthesizer, you only need to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the adobe-flashplayer that was getting a conflict (don't know why), so i just removed it and now works fine.

```
sudo apt-get purge adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the adobe-flashplugin installed so no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have resolved itself after docking it back to my ThinkPad dock that is connected to the other display I use at work. I think this somehow got it out of that option. Very odd, definitely a bug but don't know where to start with a bug report. If I come across it again I will try to document it better and post a bug report.